# Write java code in js file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to access a system property from my `.js file`.
Initially I had accessed the system property from my jsp file using the below syntax which worked just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ChatWindow(){
        var property = "<%=System.getProperty("CHAT_WINDOW_URL") %>";
        alert(property);
    }
    </script>
```

However when I tried to use the same function in `.js file`, I am getting errors that :

```
Expected ';'
```

When I do add `';'` as follows:

```
var property = "<%=System.getProperty("CHAT_WINDOW_URL"); %>";
```

or as

```
var property = "<%=System.getProperty('CHAT_WINDOW_URL') %>";
```

The error goes.. but the property value is not resolved.
Could anybody please help me on this.

Comment: are there any errors on browser console?

Comment: you DO realize that JS code runs on the client side and JSP gets compiled on the server side, so its not a good practise to mix them both as you have done.

Comment: I doubt your servlet is going to parse JSP code inside a `.js` file. Why not just revert back to setting the JS variable in your JSP file?

Comment: Actually i have 4 jsp files trying to use the same function, hence i thought it would be better to write the function in a common js file.Is it not possible to write java code in a js file?

Comment: Better you can have a common `jsp` file instead of `js` and include it in rest of the files. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks guys.. i think i will just have a common jspf file and include it in the rest of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a correct way to do it. Javascript is client side code whereas scriptlet is complied on server side. The best way to do this is by using a hidden input element.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=System.getProperty('CHAT_WINDOW_URL') %>" id="chatWindowURL" ../>
```

Now, in you javascript, write:

```
var systemURL = document.getElementById('chatWindowURL').value;
```

Comment: Or just set the `systemURL` variable in the JSP file before the external `<script>` tag.